# Parse Json file through Classes and object [C#]

Tags: c#, json.net

I've take a look at all questions regarding JSON and C# but i didn't found any solution... I'm currently studiyng C# and object/class statment but i didn't really catch how to make the stuff works all together... i didn't really catch for example when make an override, when declare a method private instead of public, when declare an interface and when a classes ... however i decided to make some example ... maybe i could understand a little bit better how the things are working ...

In this case (for example) i would like load a JSON through the classes declared, and create an object for each JSON object (take this example below that i found around the stack for example)!

This is my Class:

```
public class Cars
{
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string LicensePlate { get; set; }
    public int KM { get; set; }
    public bool Financing { get; set; }
    public int Doors { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
}
```

This is my JSON example file:

```
{
    "1":
    {
        "Manufacturer": "Fiat",
        "Model": "500",
        "Year": "2017",
        "LicensePlate": "AZ978AG",
        "KM": 120000,
        "Financing" : true,
        "Doors" : 5,
        "Cost" : 6000
    }
    ,
    "2":
    {
        "Manufacturer": "BMW",
        "Model": "Serie 1",
        "Year": "2019",
        "LicensePlate": "BC978AG",
        "KM": 150000,
        "Financing" : false,
        "Doors" : 3,
        "Cost" : 12000
    }
}
```

1. So i would like load the json, and translate all `json_object` (like: "1","2") in a `C#_object` that derived from "Cars" how can i do it?
2. There is some kind of dynamic approach that allow me to create *n* number of object without declare it one by one (like in this case: I have 2 json object, is there some kind of method for detect how many json-object are in a json file and correctly distance a dynamic number of object)?
3. Once I correctly set-up a c#_object how can i manage it? (for example, i would like print all object (with all attributes), change a value of one of attributes declared (manufacturer, model, year...) or delete once of it from the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So i would like load the json, and translate all json_object (like: "1","2") in a C#_object that derived from "Cars" how can i do it?

This code will deserialize the Json into a dictionary:

```cs
var cars = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Cars>>(carsJson);
```

> Once I correctly set-up a c#_object how can i manage it? (for example, i would like print all object (with all attributes), change a value of one of attributes declared (manufacturer, model, year...) or delete once of it from the file

You can add, remove, or change the values in the dictionary, then serialize it back to the file:

```cs
cars["1"].Year = "2020";
cars["1"].LicensePlate = "GAB293C";
cars.Remove("2");
    
var newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cars);
```

Output:

```json
{
  "1": {
    "Manufacturer": "Fiat",
    "Model": "500",
    "Year": "2020",
    "LicensePlate": "GAB293C",
    "KM": 120000,
    "Financing": true,
    "Doors": 5,
    "Cost": 6000
  }
}
```

Comment: Amazing! And if i would like print all the object ? Don't i need a class where to parse all the object? I mean, as i know you should have at least [one class "cars"](https://pastebin.com/QHNRfNYW) into the c# project

Comment: EDIT: so in the c# the class remaing invariant if i use this statmnet `var newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cars);` i mean, don't i need to delete it too in the object created inside the program?

Comment: Add i tried to use it, but seems report an execption: `Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: C. Path '', line 0, position 0.`

Comment: _"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: C. Path '', line 0, position 0"_ - that error usually means the Json is empty

Comment: To print out the object, override `ToString()` in the `Cars` class

Comment: thank you for the reply, regard the exception, i've verify, and the json seems correctly set-up as the example above.. when you talking about `"override ToString()"` you are talking about declare a method in the class "cars" that contain the virtualization of `ToString()`?

Comment: The docs on `ToString()` are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method) - regarding the Json, the example in your question worked with this code, is what you have now different to that?